# How to turn selection into dotted line?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

This line is just an expanded selection, but I need to turn it into the actual dotted line so I can print it. Any help?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use the Marquee Tool to right-click the selection, set tolerance to 0.5:

[image]

[image]

2. Use the **Shape Tool** to select the newly created work path and select the **Path** option in the upper left dropdown menu:

[image]

3. This will enable the option to convert the path into a shape. Simply click the **Shape Button** just to the right:

[image]

4. With the shape still selected, switch back the the **Shape** option in the upper left dropdown menu:

[image]

5. Edit the newly created shape as you would any shape made with the Shape tool:

[image]